# Glassfish 2.1 Spring 3.0 - How-To Setup - No Web Application

Tags: spring, glassfish

I have googled around and I have not found satisfying informations about how to start to setup spring in a glassfish container.

Starting point is:

- Glassfish 2.1 (no discussions about the version please cause we are forced to use this)
- Spring (preferrable version 3.0 but if not possible also lower version is allowed)
- EJB 3.0 (therefore I want to make use of the interceptor mechanism to inject a spring bean on the the stateless bean see: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html#ejb-implementation-ejb3 )

We don't have a web application in the ear file therefore I am lost at the moment how I could integrate spring into our ear file.

Therefore I have the following questions:

How do I have to configure glassfish/ear file to recognize the spring xml files?
Where should I place and how should I name the spring xml files so they are recognized correctly by the spring framework?

It would be great if anybody could help to find the approriate starting point.

Kind regards,
Walter